# Forgive an Invoice through a webhook with Stripe PHP Api

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Here is the premise of what I am trying to accomplish:

Stripe generates an invoice for a monthly subscription and sends a webhook to a page on my server. I receive the webhook and do a quick test to see if the user has a negative balance (financial application) in which case, I want to "forgive" the invoice. However, I can not get the Invoice to save. Code is below but would appreciate any help in solving this.

```
// Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$event_json = json_decode($input);

// Do something with $event_json
$Stripe_Cust_ID = $event_json->data->object->customer;
$Plan = $event_json->data->object->lines->data[0]->plan->id;
$Invoice_ID = $event_json->data->object->id;

//...
//Small amount of logic and a DB query to figure out user's balance.
//....

if ($Balance < 0) {
    $invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve($event_json->data->object->id);
    echo "Invoice Forgiven?: ".$invoice->forgiven;
    $invoice->forgiven = true;
    echo "Invoice Forgiven Round 2?: ".$invoice->forgiven;
    $invoice->save();
}

http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater
```

My code echo's out the full Invoice response but won't seem to forgive the invoice or save it. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting your Stripe API key using something like the following prior to calling out to Stripe's API?

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_XXYYZZ");
```

Outside of that, your request *should* work as you've coded it. I would suggest that you look in your Stripe account's API logs [0] to ensure that your requests are getting to Stripe and to see what the responses to your requests are. I would also suggest that you look at your own server's logs for any errors that may be present.

[0] https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs/overview

Comment: So it wasn't the setApiKey but I did look at the actual log and apparently Stripe requires you to close the invoice BEFORE forgiving it. That was the error. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!